# weird errors when compiling under corebuild

Tags: ocaml

I really don't understand what's going on. I have the following code:

```
let rec interleave n l = 
match l with
  [] -> [[n]]
  | head::tail -> (n::l)::(List.map (~f:fun y -> head::y) (interleave n tail))
in let rec aux l =
match l with
  [] -> [l]
  | head::tail -> List.concat ( List.map (interleave head) (aux tail) )
```

When compiling with **ocaml** it compiles and works as expected but under **corebuild** it gives me the following error:

> The expression has type 'a list -> `a list list but an expression was
>   expected of type 'b list

Does it have something to do with labels again (as you see from `~f:fun y -> ...` it has already annoyed me before)? If yes what kind of label should I use and where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reread part of manual about labeled arguments.

```
let rec interleave n l = 
match l with
  | [] -> [[n]]
  | head::tail -> (n::l)::(List.map ~f:(fun y -> head::y) (interleave n tail))
and aux l =
match l with
  | [] -> [l]
  | head::tail -> List.concat ( List.map ~f:(interleave head) (aux tail) );;
```

N.B. right syntax for labeled arguments is `~label:expression`

N.B. In Core List.map function has type `'a list -> f:('a -> 'b) -> 'b list` and if you forget to add label to your function `f` it will try to unify 2nd argument with a function. That's why you have so weird error message.

Comment: I thought function `~f` is only added to "lambda" functions but now it makes sense